# Replace None and Nan raster values with -9999.0 and divide all values by 1000

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to replace all None and/or nan values in the numpy array with -9999.0 and then divide all the array values by 1000. All my attempts have been met with the error, TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.  Please help.

```
    stats = np.array([x['sum'] for x in stats])

    stats = stats/1000
```

Comment: NaNs or Nones, or both? Can you show (a part of) your `stats` variable?

Comment: Given the TypeError, your problem is probably located in the *format* of your original `stats` value; you should post that original `stats` variable (or at least a relevant part of it), and post the *full* traceback.

Comment: I apologize I did not see these comments until now.  The original stats is a list of dictionaries using the rasterstats library.  The format is something like this:  

[{'__fid__': 0, 'sum': 20}, {'__fid__': 1,'sum': 15}, etc.].  

def assess_costs(output_df,cost_file,cost_surface,params):

        stats =  rs.zonal_stats(output_df.to_crs(epsg=5070).geometry.values,cost_surface,transform=cost_file.GetGeoTransform(),stats=('sum'))

        stats = np.array([x['sum'] for x in stats])

        stats = stats/1000
        output_df['impact'] = stats
        return output_df

This is the function.

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30700329/edit) your question, and put the values and traceback inside the question. That gives you more formatting options and keeps thing together. It's clearer than putting all that code in a comment.

Comment: But with your given example of `stats` (array of dicts), I can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `stats` array apparently contains both `NaN`s and `None` values, your array dtype will be `np.object`. Probably the easiest way is then to iterate over the array and create a new one, replacing values in the process. For example:

```
>>> stats = [1, 2, 3, np.nan, None, 6]
>>> a = np.array([-9999 if x is None or np.isnan(x) else x for x in stats])
>>> a
array([    1,     2,     3, -9999, -9999,     6])
```

More easy, you can set the dtype to `np.float`, which will implicitly convert `None` to `np.nan`:

```
>>> stats = np.array(stats, dtype=np.float)
>>> stats[np.isnan(stats)] = -9999
```

But you may want to consider using [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) instead:

```
>>> stats = [1, 2, 3, np.nan, None, 6]
>>> stats = np.array(stats, dtype=np.float)
>>> stats
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,  nan,  nan,   6.])
>>> a = np.ma.array(stats, mask=np.isnan(stats), fill_value=-9999)
>>> a / 1000
masked_array(data = data = [0.001 0.002 0.003 -- -- 0.006],
             mask = [False False False  True  True, False],
             fill_value = -9999.0)
```

Comment: Attempted to use the masked array technique but still getting the TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars error. hmmmmm. 


stats = np.array([x['sum'] for x in stats], dtype=np.float)
        
a = np.ma.array(stats, mask=np.isnan(stats), fill_value=-9999)
              
stats_new = a/1000
        
output_df['impact'] = stats_new

Comment: You're not showing what the original `stats` looks like (see my original comment to your question); without that, we can't help you further.

Answer (score 1):

This code finds all the values that are not floats (in this case None) in array and replace them by -9999. The last step is to divide everything by 1000:

```
array = np.array([None, 1.1, 2.1, 3.3, 4.5, None, 5.1, 6.0])
idxs = np.where([type(val) != float for val in array])[0]
array[idxs] = -9999
array = array/1000
```

I believe you can adapt this solution to your needs.